# Laravel division by zero if date is today

Tags: php, date, laravel

I'm trying to make some stats for my website.

But I have the problem that if I use the code I got now, when it is a dy like today, so the first day of the month, I got the error `division by zero`.

My code:

```
$begin = date('Y-m-01');
$end = date('Y-m-t');
$begin = new \DateTime($begin);
$end = new \DateTime('now');
$diff = $end->diff($begin); // creates a DateInterval object
$days = (int)$diff->format('%a'); // %a  -->  days
$average_visits = $get_visits / $days;
```

It does work, when the day isn't 01 or 1.

How can I fix his issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$days` actually is `zero`!

#### Explanation

Today is `2015-07-01` (at least here at my timezone)

you define `$begin = date('Y-m-01');` which is `2015-07-01`

you define `$end = new \DateTime('now');` which is `2015-07-01`

you want to know the difference in days which is `0`

```
$diff = $end->diff($begin);
$days = (int)$diff->format('%a');
```

you divide a unknown number `$get_visits` by `$days` (which is zero).
So you get the correct error `division by zero`.

#### Possible Solution

If you mean that `$days` fully includes the beginning day and the end day then use

```
$days = (int)$diff->format('%a') + 1;
```

Then

```
a) begin = 2015-07-01, end = 2015-07-01
b) begin = 2015-07-01, end = 2015-07-05
```

a) means this is `1` day
b) means these are `5` days (day 2015-07-01, day 2015-07-02, day 2015-07-03, day 2015-07-04 and day 2015-07-05 makes 5 days)

Comment: I know I got an correct error, but how can I fix that?

Comment: The edit doesn't help me alot, the system worked! exept when the day is the first day of the month.

Comment: just guessing what you want to do and posted a possible solution. Maybe you need to rethink what you want to archive and find another approach.  But again mathematically it is impossible to divide by zero so there is no fix for it. The 'fix' would be to ensure that `$days` is not zero before dividing.

Comment: no there must be a misconception in your approach. If beginning and end is the same day then the difference in `$days` is `0` thats a mathematical fact. And also a mathematical fact is that you can't divide any number by zero. So find your misconception.

Comment: Yeah, I looked already for it, but I don't find it? That's why I'm asking it to the community.

Comment: This is why I posted a solution, because I guess if you say beginning is 2015-07-01 and end is 2015-07-01 you mean this is ONE day and not ZERO days which leads into the `+1` I posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82072/discussion-between-robin-r-and-peh).